# Using NuxtJS for dynamic routes without server target

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I always thought that frontend should not be over bloated in size, usually by "frontend" I imagined a set of HTML, CSS and JS files, which are kind of small, especially when minified and compressed. So you can use whatever framework or library you love, your dev node_modules could be enormous in size, but after the compilation you get something lightweight to be served e.g by Nginx. Yeah, I just described an SPA-like setup, not an SSR when there's a server process running.

I had an experience building a website with NuxtJS, and it has only runtime logic, so no backend was required. I just did `yarn generate` and served all the resulted static with Nginx.

Now I'm building an application which requires a backend (it's a separate Python process), with dynamic pages like `/users/john` and `/users/jane`. Nuxt documentation says I can't use `generate` option anymore, cause such routing is dynamic. *(technically I can write a set of fetch functions to load users from API during build time and generate corresponding pages, but it doesn't work well for runtime data)*. The only option is to use server target of NuxtJs.

There's even a [page](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/deployment/nginx-proxy/) describing how to serve Nuxt application with Nginx. It assumes you should use `yarn start` command, which starts a Node process. It works fine, dynamic content is routed, caching is performed by Nginx, but.. it doesn't fit in a model that "frontend is lightweight". I use docker, and it means that now I need to bring huge `node_modules` with me. `nuxt` package itself is about 200 MB, which is kinda big for a small frontend app. I can run `yarn install --production` to save some space, but it still doesn't solve an issue that resulted image is huge.

Previously, when I wrote some apps in React, they resulted in a single `index.html` which I served by Nginx. It means, such dynamic routing was handled by frontend, using `react-router` or similar stuff.

To better understand my concerns, here's some rough comparison:

- **My old React apps**: ~5 MB of disk space, 0 RAM, 0 CPU, routing is done by `index.html` file
- **My previous site with Nuxt static option**: ~5 MB of disk space, 0 RAM, 0 CPU, routing is done by file system (`/page1/index.html`, `/page2/index.html`)
- **My current site with Nuxt server option**: ~ 400 MB or even more disk space for a docker image,  RAM,  CPU, routing is done by Nuxt runtime

I don't really want to overcomplicate things. Allocating a lot of resources for a simple web app is too much, especially when you can solve the task with a help of a few static files.

The questions are:

1. Am I missing some option in NuxtJS to solve my issue?
2. Am I just misusing NuxtJS, and it's better to get plain VueJS, some vue-router, and develop the app as I described in "previously with react" section?

Comment: There is also the option to render in SPA mode, where data is fetched and rendered client-side. mode set to SPA. https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-mode. Is that an option for you to dynamically fetch data and render client-side?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making a mistake here about `SPA` mode.

Assume that you have a page named `users` in your `Nuxt pages`, your folder structure is like this:

```
[pages]
    [users]
        [_name]
            index.vue
```

When you requesting `/users/john` you can take the john from `params` and making an `axios` call to your server.

After that, you can use the `nuxt generate` command to create your `dist` folder and after that serve the `dist` folder with `Nginx`. Everything will work fine.

Comment: I did exactly what you suggested. The problem is that Nuxt won't generate anything for `users`. It's kind of expected; if you don't know the `_name` in build time, how would you generate static .html for it? In SPA it's solved by serving "main" `index.html` always, and JS does the routing

Comment: You need to create a function and use it in `nuxt.config.js` with `generate: {}` https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate/

Answer (score 0):

Check this simple routing approach in the browser

```html
const routes = {
  '/': Home,
  '/users': Users
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    currentRoute: window.location.pathname
  },
  computed: {
    ViewComponent () {
      return routes[this.currentRoute] || NotFound
    }
  },
  render (h) { return h(this.ViewComponent) }
})
```

In the Users component integrate with your python backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SPA mode in NuxtJS (`mode: 'spa',` or `ssr: false,` in latest versions), then run `yarn generate` or `nuxt generate`, it will generate a full bundle in `dist` folder that can be served with any HTTP server.

This works fine with all dynamic routes, I tested it with simple `php -S localhost:8000` that's just serves a folder via HTTP.

This works due to a trick with 200.html https://dev.to/adnanbabakan/deploy-a-single-page-application-with-200-html-2p0f

For my project it generated all needed data and folder size is just 13mb (with all images, fonts, etc...).

You can read more about how static routing is done in Nuxt docs: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations